# SQL Developer 4.0 extensions not loading

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, jdeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I've recently downloaded the new SQL Developer 4.0 tool, and moved my usually used extensions to it. But while after i started the software my extensions weren't there ! not loaded at all and no log about them when i activated debug logging mode !

Any body has an idea on how to load extensions in 4.0 version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [the early adopter release announcement](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/07/oracle-sql-developer-4-0-is-finally-here/):

> All 3rd party extensions are currently disabled – our framework has
>   changed such that they will need to be updated to be compatible with
>   the new version

The extension developers will need to update their extensions; if there is not already a new version available you'll need to contact them directly to ask for this to be done, it's not something Oracle has control over really. [This](https://forums.oracle.com/message/11120333) and [this](https://forums.oracle.com/message/11193112) might also be of interest. As mentioned in the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-releasenotes-v4-1925251.html), issues with the early-adopter version should be reported on the [SQL Developer forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=260).

Comment: Thank you. I've passed lot of time looking for right information, but you suggested links are just right on target.